# What does "insult" refer to?

Tags: plot-explanation, bombshell

In *Bombshell* (2019), Lily reads the message from her phone to Megyn:

> Lily: Frank Bruni in The Times. The debate was riveting. It was
> admirable. It compels me to write a cluster of words I never  imagined
> writing: - hooray for Fox News.
>
> Gil (to Megyn):  Well, that’s gotta make you happy, praise all
> tangled up in an **insult**.

I don’t see any negative opinions in the words said by Frank Bruni
in The Times.

What does "insult" refer to ?

Comment: "*I never imagined writing: - hooray for Fox News*" -> you're such a bunch of *** that this one (win) is only a one-shot, but GG anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **It compels me to write a cluster of words I never imagined writing:** "hooray for [Fox News](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox_News#Ratings_and_reception)."

Bruni says the equivalent of "I never thought I'd say this, but, good job!" Or to someone's appearance: "You look great, for once!" It's a compliment with a "but..." attached: complimenting the 1%-of-the-time while insulting the 99%-of-the-time.

Incidentally, this episode apparently comes straight from Megyn Kelly's book *Settle for More*:

> Frank Bruni's in the New York Times was particularly memorable. The debate was "riveting," Bruni wrote. "It was admirable. It compels me to write a cluster of words I never imagined writing: hooray for Fox News." **Once again, the insult tied to the compliment.**

And see Frank Bruni's whole 2015-08-06 opinion column, titled "A Foxy, Rowdy Republican Debate," [here](https://archive.is/EpRKo).